# What does the parameter code of this method mean?

Tags: c++, templates, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

As the title says, `TBitArray<>` does not have an exact type, so does it mean that this method can accept any such as `TBitArray<int32>`, `TBitArray<float>`, ... as parameters?

```cpp
FORCEINLINE bool HasAll(const TBitArray<>& Other) const
{
    FConstWordIterator ThisIterator(*this);
    FConstWordIterator OtherIterator(Other);

    while (ThisIterator || OtherIterator)
    {
        const uint32 A = ThisIterator ? ThisIterator.GetWord() : 0;
        const uint32 B = OtherIterator ? OtherIterator.GetWord() : 0;
        if ((A & B) != B)
        {
            return false;
        }

        ++ThisIterator;
        ++OtherIterator;
    }

    return true;
}
```

And what difference with this code

```cpp
template<class T>
FORCEINLINE bool HasAll(const TBitArray<T>& Other) const
```

Comment: just in case...if you know java generics, this is not like them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TBitArray<>` is a template class with all default template parameters. If it's `TBitArray<int32>` or `TBitArray<float>` depends on the template definition.

[Here](https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/blob/47b66ccfd820fb3a982c31b34a29b4887bbb64cc/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Public/Containers/BitArray.h#L51) is its definition:

```
template<typename Allocator = FDefaultBitArrayAllocator>
class TBitArray;
```

So, it's neither `int32` nor `float`, it's the default array allocator.

Comment: If the template parameter expects an allocator, then how would types like `TBitArray<int32>` and `TBitArray<float>` even work in the first place?

Comment: @RemyLebeau They cannot work, they are OP assumptions, but not valid.

Comment: OK, so now I see from [Unreal's documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.1/en-US/API/Runtime/Core/Containers/TBitArray/) that `TBitArray` is just a dynamic array of bits, and you can't instantiate a type like `TBitArray<int32>` or `TBitArray<float>` in the first place. Got it, thanks

Answer (score 2):

> so does it mean that this method can accept any such as `TBitArray<int32>`, `TBitArray<float>`, ... as parameters?

No.

From the definition of the [`TBitArray`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.1/en-US/API/Runtime/Core/Containers/TBitArray/) class:

```
template<typename Allocator = FDefaultBitArrayAllocator>
class TBitArray;
```

You can see that its template argument takes an `Allocator` type, and defaults to [`FDefaultBitArrayAllocator`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/API/Runtime/Core/Containers/FDefaultBitArrayAllocator/).  So, `TBitArray<>` is just shorthand for `TBitArray<FDefaultBitArrayAllocator>`.